# Magento product image not uploading in localhost

Tags: php, magento-1.9

Product image is not getting upload on localhost, whenever I click "upload images" it shows red border on images and not uploading. Also this thing working fine at live site

[image]

Comment: what's your php version? what's the environment looks like? using xampp, on windows ? mamp linux ?

Comment: If you are adding product image store wise then, select your store from left top corner on the page and save image.